# Windows 10 Wi-Fi too slow on Bootcamp after update

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp, wifi-configuration

My MacBook Pro 2016 Touchbar had Windows 10 installed using Boot Camp. But in the same WiFi, macOS has 3 Mbps speed. While in Windows, the speed is lower than 10 Kbps... and it has a lot of timeout when using ping cmd.

Comment: Do you have the proper and most up to date wireless driver for windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

Solved. This seems a problem of power management.

To fix it, go to power management settings and find the Wi-Fi part. Set the value of Using Battery on Power Saving Mode to Max Performance. Then restart Windows.

[image]

I think this is a bug in Windows because I had this problem when I used with power plugged in...

Comment: Also, there could be some interfere between 2.4GHz wifi and USB type-C data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

For me, on old Macbook5,1 - The Macbook late 2008 aluminium model.
Very Slow wifi download but fast upload while running Windows 10 32bit on it, from the BOOTCAMP partition.

The hardware id of my "Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter" wifi card is
PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_432B&SUBSYS_008D106B, which led me to
The driver that works perfectly is this one
http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/utils/Bluetooth_XPWin7_VER510082112.zip
(Update the Driver via Device Manager and browser to the extracted zip location.)

I found it on through this site which has the link to the manufacturer direct download:
https://www.driveridentifier.com/scan/broadcom-80211n-network-adapter-driver/driver-detail/FB530C2CC42E4B7E97347453DC0E5570/1301079/6c1f9916615aa1b8d755962ecef8361a/115853431/PCI-VEN_14E4%26DEV_432b

Try the same for yours, search by Device Hardware ID.