# WiFI does not work on Windows 10 BootCamp - Drops in and out

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, boot-camp

**Update (7/9/2018): There was a new driver released on 4/20/2018 for Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter, version 7.35.118.83, but the Apple update is only now pushing it.  Just installed it. Let's see how it goes.**

**Background-**  Network works fine, router works fine, connections is perfect when running Mac OS. I happens on every wireless network I use. I already submitted this question in the Apple StackExchange, but after some research it's leading me to believe this is a Windows 10 problem:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314210/wifi-does-not-work-on-windows-10-bootcamp-drops-in-and-out

**Attempted solutions-** I tried the methods suggested in these webpages (and many more):

http://www.mweb.co.za/games/view/tabid/4210/Article/22103/Windows-10-Random-Disconnect-Issue-and-Fixes.aspx

http://www.mweb.co.za/games/view/tabid/4210/Article/22103/Windows-10-Random-Disconnect-Issue-and-Fixes.aspx

**New information-** Something that seems to have helped, but did not fix the problem was unchecking "Allow computer to turn off this device to save power". Although, somehow the device still got turned off.

I've been pinging my router consistently since yesterday. I can't find any correlation between toggling options, and ping time. Sometimes it's consistently <1ms, majority of the time its between 1-5ms, with 20ms hiccups and random Request Timeouts, then sometimes it there are lags of 200ms to 3,000ms pings with extended time outs; At which point I delete the Networ Adapter driver, and reinstall. Again, I can't seem to find any rhyme or reason as to what's causing this variability in connection.

My guess is that there may be some cache or registry where information begins to build up and causes it to slow down.

**Question-** Is there a way to diagnose the cause of these spike in ping lag?

**Update-** Mac OS is also exhibiting ping lag and Request Timeouts.  However, connection is seamless when streaming and browsing, with no connection drops or lags.

**Network Adapter Info-**

en0:
  Card Type:    AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x173)

Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.130.1a1)

Locale:   FCC

Country Code: X0

Supported PHY Modes:  802.11 a/b/g/n/ac

Supported Channels:   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140, 144, 149, 153, 157, 161, 165

**Previous post-**

WiFi is consistently dropping at random times regardless of network.

Question : how do I fix it so I have a reliable consistent wifi connection when I use Windows 10?

I have a MacBook Pro, purchased late 2017.

WiFi will randomly disconnect when I run Windows 10. It works better on certain networks than others but it's always intermittent. Even on very robust networks it will eventually begin to drop. Once it drops it sometimes will simply not reconnect. Other times the drivers will randomly be disabled, not sure if this has to do with windows updates.

I tried manually installing and uninstalling drivers, rolling back drivers, installing and reinstalling the windows support software, and even using third party driver support software. Wifi connection still drops randomly with no perceivable pattern.

I went to the apple store and I was simply told that this is a windows issue. I had windows running on a MacBook air (2010) and never experienced these issues. It also seems they haven't come up with an update for the driver in almost two years. I ran out of ideas, any pointers on how to fix the wifi connection problem is appreciated.

Hardware info -

Manufacturer: Broadcom

Description: Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter

Driver version: 7.35.118.68

Comment: Router make and model? What's the specific model number of your wifi adapter?

Comment: Router: Actiontec MI424WR

I am now pinging in Mac OS - Looks like the same problem exists, with occasional time outs as well.  However, it is not noticeable when streaming or web browsing.

Comment: I suggest first of all assuring you have the recommended wireless encryption settings at the router: WPA2-AES only. No WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and especially not TKIP. Broadcoms are notorious for having an issue with other thasn this recommended settings in certain cases, maily in Linux but other OSes can be affected as well. Also update the drivers if available.

Comment: I think I exhausted all the options when it comes to drivers, I can't find any more recent drivers, even though this driver is from 2016. Maybe with the device options there could be something I can change.  

Though, I may fix this problem if a reconfigure the router.  But this is a problem that happens on every network I connected so I am hoping for a solution that is router independent.

Comment: What's the model # of the adapter? MichealBay is correct in saying AES ONLY. Even 802.11n will fall back to 54Mbps when using tkip. And other problems in general. If it's connecting the same on other networks(unless they are in the same vicinity) rules out environmental. I'm leaning on the adapter or drivers here.

Comment: Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter, not sure if you're asking for something more specific.

Also, some networks it has better connections.  But there is still an eventual drop, even on really good networks.

Comment: Yea, the model number should be on the adapter somewhere. (Usually the sticker on the underside)

Comment: I added an Edit.  Look at Network Adapter Info in my post.

Comment: look for U-APSD support in the advanced settings of your adapter (device manager). i would additionally check out settings for 802.11h, i am not sure if Verizons routers support it though.

Comment: No options available for U-APSD. There is an option for strict 11h.  Looking at the router, compatability options are only b/g/n.  Nothing about h. I changed the options so the router workins in WPA2-AES only (I think, can't tell with the settings).  Too early to tell if it made a differences, I'll have to keep monitoring my connection.

Comment: it may also be listed as "WMM-Power save" or similar. it varies from adapter to adapter, and sometimes even driver versions. 802.11h i believe is wireless-a/ac compatible. i would have to double check its compatibility to be perfectly honest with you.

Comment: Thanks found it, set WMM to 'Disabled'.  Again, I'll have to wait to see if the internet remain stable.

Comment: Cool, let us know if it worked, I'll add it as the answer if it does.

Comment: Hi Tim, after a few days there still seems to be a problem with drops. I did manage however to mitigate the problem, I found that I can stream without any connection drops when I close all of the applications that are pinging in the background (updates, skype, outlook, dropbox etc). It seems to be some kind of bottle-necking issue.  On a seperate note, the network adapter disabled itself every time after trying to connect to a different network, it didn't happen before.  I think I'm going to do clean re-install of windows.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still have this problem but I had this issue and after months I finally found a fix that worked for me.  I used this random lonovo driver found here https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds103679 .  I Found it by checking out which driver my GF was using on her older MBP on windows 10, and this one was very similar.  It seems to have completely fixed this issue for me, hope it helps you as well!

Answer (score 0):

The drivers in Windows 10 aren't ideal.

- You need to find out the hardware id of your network adapter/wifi card.
- `(press Cmd-X) -> Device Manager -> Network adapters -> Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter -> Details tab -> Property dropdown -> Hardware ID's`
- The hardware ID is like a form of `PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_432B&SUBSYS_008D106B`
- Search https://www.driveridentifier.com for a version for that hardware id.

For me it fixed the slowness with the proper driver for it: https://superuser.com/a/1652134/35525